# Failing to PassRole with iam:PassedToService for CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to allow users to execute `codebuild:StartBuild`, while restricting `iam:PassRole` to pass the custom codebuild role only to the CodeBuild service.

The canned policies never restrict `iam:PassRole`, and even use `"Resource":"*"`, effectively allowing passing of any role to any service. This strikes me as a bit sloppy, but maybe it's just me.

The policy below is an excerpt – `codebuild:StartBuild`, `codebuild:List*`, etc, are all allowed.

```js
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {   "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/my-codebuild-role",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy makes `codebuild:StartBuild` return an error:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/MyDevRole/me@example.com
  is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource:
    arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my-codebuild-role
```

**Now, removing the `Condition` part of the policy makes `codebuild:StartBuild` succeed.**

The CloudTrail logs state exactly the same, without providing any additional information, neither in that particular event, nor in events before or after it.

I have also tried variations of the `Condition` match, including: Specify `codebuild.amazonaws.com` as the service; specify `codebuild.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` as the service; ditto using `StringEquals`; specifying a list of all AWS principals and using `ForAnyValue:StringLike`.

It doesn't make sense that a `StringLike` match on `*` fails, while removing the `Condition` altogether makes it work.

What am I doing wrong? What is AWS not telling me? Or, what is AWS doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem but when I insert a condition on AssumeRolePolicyDocument. I've tested many conditions as you did and none of them worked.

Comment: So StringEqualsIfExists works. Which makes me think codebuild.amazonaws.com is not present in the request.

Comment: CodeBuild + CodeCommit do not support the `PassedToService` condition apparently: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#ck_PassedToService